# how to convert the type text of MySQL to String in java

Tags: java, mysql, string, text

I have a probleme in my application.
In fact I do not know how to convert the type text of MySQL to String in java ??
thank you.

Comment: More details: which framework are you using? jdbc? then just ResultSet.getString() should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = resultSet.getString("MyTextColumn");
```

Or maybe so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    resultSet.getClob("MyTextCLOB").getCharacterStrean());
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   sb.append(line).append("\r\n");
}
value = sb.toString();
```

Best guess

```
Reader in = resultSet.getCharacterStream("MyColumn");
```

See [ResultSet.getCharacterStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getCharacterStream%28java.lang.String%29).

---

***Aha!***

As I understand now there was a problem in the code like:

```
final String sql = "SELECT description FROM annonce";
try (PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        String description = rs.getString("description");
        System.out.println("# " + description);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

There was some null returned. `description` indeed can be null, if the database field `description` can be (SQL) NULL, To prevent that:

```
CREATE TABLE annonce (
    description TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

or skipt the values:

```
final String sql =
    "SELECT description FROM annonce WHERE description IS NOT NULL";
```

Comment: In fact, the problem is caused by my request SQL:
select description from annonce returns null because the field description has the type text !!!